# How to resolve 'za' error in OPEN LAYERS 3 map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

When I am try to animate the map on the basis pf markers fetching. Till sometime map line animation is working properly but after sometime the line animation stops and when I see the browser's console I see :
Cannot get the property 'za' of undefined.
How to get rid of this.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be very useful some code or better yet, a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: A first step is to use `ol-debug.js` instead of `ol.js` to get a better error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ol-debug.js` this will give you a more informative error, and allow you to step through the library using a browser's developer tools.

When bug fixing, or developing, I usually have a commented out bit of html to pull in an `ol-debug.js` cdn as needed, and switch with `ol.js`:

```
<!--  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.14.0/ol-debug.js"></script>-->
```

Comment: You mean I should comment the ol-debug.js ?